# awk output to variable and change directory

Tags: perl, variables, awk, chdir

In the below script. am not able to change the directory.i need the output like above 70% disk inside that directory which one is consuming more space.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $test=qx("df -h |awk \+\$5>=70 {print \$6} ");
chdir($test) or die "$!";
print $test;
system("du -sh * | grep 'G'");
```

Comment: Where do you think the problem is? In the `perl` code? In the `awk` code? What is the expected output? What is the real output?

Comment: its not changing the direrctoy. actually I need like  above 70% disk inside that  disk which directory is consuming more space

Comment: Then why do you not swap the perl lines `chdir`and `print` in order to print the output of `df -h`?

Comment: Did yo u know that the `df -h` command splits long lines in two ones and then `awk`  code may not work?

Comment: @Jdamian That's where the ’-P’ switch kicks in.

Comment: I don't know perl but if calling awk from inside perl is the right thing to do then perl must have a stunning hole in it's functionality.

Comment: the above script is working fine till "my $test=qx("df -h |awk \+\$5>=70 {print \$6} ");" after that not able to change directory. please help. one more whether its good use awk inside the perl script?

Answer (score 3):

No need to call `awk` in your case because Perl is quite good at splitting and printing certain lines itself. Your code has some issues:

1. The code `qx("df -h |awk \+\$5>=70 {print \$6} ")` tries to execute the ***string*** `"df -h | awk ..."` as a command which fails because there is no such command called `"df -h | awk"`. When I run that code I get `sh: 1: df -h |awk +>=70 {print } : not found`. You can fix that by dropping the quotes `"` because `qx()` already *is* quoting. The variable `$test` is empty afterwards, so the `chdir` changes to your `$HOME` directory.
2. Then you'll see the next error: `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near end of line`, because it calls `awk +\$5>=70 {print \$6}`. Correct would be `awk '+\$5>=70 {print \$6}'`, i.e. with ticks `'` around the `awk` scriptlet.
3. As stated in a comment, `df -h` splits long lines into two lines. Example:

   ```
   Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
   /long/and/possibly/remote/file/system
                        10735331328 10597534720 137796608  99% /local/directory
   ```

   Use `df -hP` to get guaranteed column order and *one line output*.
4. The last `system` call shows the directory usage (space) for all lines containing the letter `G`. I reckon that's not exactly what you want.

I suggest the following Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $line ( qx(df -hP) ) {
    my ($fs, $size, $used, $avail, $use, $target) = split(/\s+/, $line);
    next unless ($use =~ /^\d+\s*\%$/); # skip header line

    # now $use is e.g. '90%' and we drop the '%' sign:
    $use =~ s/\%$//;

    if ($use > 70) {
        print "almost full: $target; top 5 directories:\n";

        # no need to chdir here. Simply use $target/* as search pattern,
        # reverse-sort by "human readable" numbers, and show the top 5:
        system("du -hs $target/* 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | head -5");
        print "\n\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @bigd = map { my @f = split " "; $f[5] } 
           grep { my @f = split " "; $f[4] =~ /^(\d+)/ && $1 >= 70} 
           split "\n", `df -hP`;
print "big directories: $_\n" for @bigd;
for my $bigd (@bigd) {
    chdir($bigd);
    my @bigsubd = grep { my @f = split " "; $f[0] =~ /G/ }
                  split "\n", `du -sh *`;
    print "big subdirectories in $bigd:\n";
    print "$_\n" for @bigsubd;
}
```

I belive you wanted to do something like this.